# Duplicate Plank

Tags: plank

When I turned on my computer plank was duplicated. I have no idea why. I have moved the second plank to the side of the screen to show them both using: plank --preferences.

The left plank is the real plank and it is the only one that I can control. the bottom one is stuck there but the apps on it change according to the 'main' one

Please tell me how to fix this

Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the docks you don't want any more from `net.launchpad.plank enabled-docks` :

```
gsettings reset net.launchpad.plank enabled-docks
```

via the command line or by the *dconf Editor*.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I worked it out by doing multiplank -d as I had installed i earlier